# Python Print list on separate lines

Tags: python, list, printing

I'm trying to print my leader board out however its printing it on one line instead of multiple.

So far this is my code:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT username, score FROM Players order by score DESC limit 5')
topscore = cursor.fetchall()

topscore = list(topscore)

print(topscore)
```

And when it runs it outputs like this:
[('VortexHD', 6), ('test', 0), ('TestOCR', 0)]

However i want it to output the names and score on separate lines like this:

VortexHD, 6

Test, 0

TestOCR, 0

any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.execute('SELECT username, score FROM Players order by score DESC limit 5')
topscore = cursor.fetchall()

topscore = list(topscore)
for i in topscore:
    print(i[0],i[1],sep=' , ')
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

`print` automatically adds an endline, so just iterate and print each value seperately:

```py
for score in topscore:
    print(score)
```

Comment: Shorter: `'\n'.join(topscore)`

Comment: @DroidX86 not as idiomatic tho

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over the output and print its every element. You don't have to create a list of the output first, since `fetchall()` returns a list already, so you can do it like this:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT username, score FROM Players order by score DESC limit 5')
topscore = cursor.fetchall()

for username, score in topscore:  # this uses tuple unpacking
    print(username, score)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> VortexHD, 6
> Test, 0
> TestOCR, 0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a predefined format if you use print(a_variable) then it will go to next line automatically.So, to get the required solution you need to print first element in tuple followed ',' and then second element by accessing with index number.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT username, score FROM Players order by score DESC limit 5')
topscore = cursor.fetchall()  
topscore = list(topscore)

for value in topscore:
    print(value[0],',',value[1])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.